# Как программно экспортировать из rvt в fbx?

Tags: c#, api, fbx, ironpython

Мне необходимо через скрипт из модели в формате Revit(rvt) экспортировать в отдельную папку fbx, желательно в фоновом режиме (без открытия самой модели). При этом скрипт подразумевает вызов графического окна в котором выбираются нужные Файлы и папка вывода fbx-ов.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно использовать. Язык либо c# либо (iron)Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с Revit нужны библиотеки RevitApi.dll  RevitApiUI.dll которые вы найдете в папке самого ревита. Подключаем их к проекту в VS, и далее идем в документацию читать что нам нужно. Для выгрузки конкретно FBX нам нужен FBXEport. Проект должен быть библиотекой классов. Компилируем dll и закидываем ее в revit addins. Так же нужно добавить файл конфигурации с расширением addin в эту папку, в ней мы укажем что именно нужно запускать ревиту и как.